# Positioning :before and :afer psudo-classes outside parent division

Tags: html, css

I have a division that has a background image but it needs to be a varible size. I'm using three images. One of the top, one for the bottom and a repeating one for the middle.

I've only got one div to work with and given the middle background image to that and then used the before and after pesudo classes to place the other images. The image from the main division shows up behind these two since they are semi transparent. Is there a way round this in css or a better method to do it?

HHTML:

```
<div class="faq">
  <strong>Q.&nbsp;Who was the greatest business man?</strong><br />
  <p><strong>A.&nbsp;</strong>Noah. He kept his stock afloat, while the rest of the world went into liquidation.</p><br />
  <strong>Q.&nbsp;How should my employees let off steam?</strong><br />
  <p><strong>A.&nbsp;</strong>Take them see to see the comedian Sampson. He'll bring the house down.</p><br />
</div>
```

CSS - style

```
.faq{
  background: transparent url(../images/image_middle.png) repeat-y center;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
.faq:before {
  background: transparent url(../images/image_top.png) no-repeat center top !important;
}
.faq:after {
  background: transparent url(../images/image_bottom.png) no-repeat center bottom !important;
}
```

CSS - layout

```
.faq:before {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    content: "\A";
}
.faq:after {
    padding-top: 14px;
    display: block;
    content: "\A";
}
.faq{
    margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
    padding: 0 20px 0 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are currently using

Comment: You can use absolute-positioning with :before and :after, but please show your code.

Comment: Have you considered using multiple background images?  http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Diodeus
To use absolute positioning I need to have the parent with relative position to position is relative to the parent rather than the page.
Would the parent in this case be the element I'm putting the before and after on is would it be different?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using multiple backgrounds - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds. in this way, you can specify the 3 different images and their positions as styles for the element. List the top image first.

If your browser support requirements won't work with CSS multiple backgrounds, you can get the same result by styling other elements - such as a `h1` or `p:last` inside your `div`. This approach is more complicated, since you have to be very careful about the position of elements inside that `div`.

Note that a background or image will **always** show through transparent areas of an image above it.  If you don't want this, you must put something opaque into that cover-up image - such as the background color that you're trying to fade to.

For more detailed help, please post a self contained example of the code you're working with.

Comment: Can you use multiple backgrounds when I middle one needs to be tiled?

Comment: @RichardYoung - Yes, the Mozilla reference page I've linked to demonstrates this.  Thanks for posting your code above - but how can I see the images you're using?